# What is a rabbit's field of vision, range and visual acuity?

Tags: rabbits, biology, vision, hearing

I have a pet house rabbit, rabbit eyes are pretty much on the side of their head. They also have great big ears.

[image]

What can a rabbit really see? How well can they see? Can they see 360 degrees?

Comment: I know this sounds stupid but one thing my 5th grade teacher taught me was that they are prey because they have eyes on the side so that they can hide but predators have eyes in the front so that they can hunt so it is for hiding from predators and to find an easy hiding spot it is just their adaptation

Answer (score 1):

Rabbit's can't see a full 360 but they certainly have greater peripheral vision than humans and other animals with eyes that are placed more forward on the face. Their one "blind spot" tends to be [right in front of their nose](https://rabbit.org/what-do-rabbits-see/).

As suggested in the comments part of the reason for rabbit's eye placement and vision is so they can better spot predators.

Rabbits also have a [third eyelid](https://www.rabbitcaretips.com/do-rabbits-blink-their-eyes/) which helps give the illusion that they are awake because their eyes tend to appear open even when they are resting. Again this is to help ward off predators.