# Do house rabbits depend more on sound or vision for warning?

Tags: rabbits, safety, biology

In the related question [What is a rabbit's field of vision, range and visual acuity?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7082) we learn about a rabbits vision.  This question is asking about what is the primary sense a house rabbit uses for danger warning eyes or ears.

They have eyes on the side of their head, and those great big ears. Which sense are they more dependent on for warning signs?  Does being a lop (floppy ear bunny) have an impact on the answer?

Comment: It was explained to me that they basically see movement but they can see movement in very low light.  But not much more than shapes and shadows.  However they have excellent hearing and smell.

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 pet bunnies. I have spent a lot of time watching them and have also done some reading. I have learned that rabbits depend on their sense of hearing and smell primarily. Their eyes are located on either side of their head, limiting their visual field, but rabbits have extremely keen hearing and move their ears accordingly in order to hear even better.

Comment: Can you add some supporting references to this answer?